# Execute a mysql stored procedure from the definer account, without execute privileges

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, privileges, execute

I created a stored procedure in my mariaDB database. The definer is a restricted user which has no EXECUTE privilege (at db, table, and procedure levels).

But I can successfully execute this procedure from this account.

Is this a normal behavior, that the definer may execute the procedure even if it has no EXECUTE privilege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-privileges.html):

> The EXECUTE privilege is required to execute stored routines. However, **this privilege is granted automatically to the creator of a routine** if necessary (and dropped from the creator when the routine is dropped). Also, the default SQL SECURITY characteristic for a routine is DEFINER, which enables users who have access to the database with which the routine is associated to execute the routine.

Comment: Thanks, I did look in the documentation but did not find this. Where is it?

Comment: @galinette, Relevant manual section is already linked in the answer ;)